# which of the following statement is true for the given option?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$  be a linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $n \geq 3$, and let
$\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_n \in \mathbb{C}$(complex field)  be the eigenvalues of $T$. Which of the following statements are true?

- List item

(a) If $\lambda_i = 0$, for some $i = 1,\dots, n$, then $T$ is not surjective.

(b) If $T$ is injective, then $\lambda_i = 1$, for some $i = 1,\dots, n$.

(c) If there is a $3$-dimensional subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $T(U) = U$, then
$\lambda_i \in\mathbb{R}$, for some $i = 1,\dots, n$.

i was trying this  question. from my point of view  if all the eigenvalue is zero , then it will be onto because it contain all the range i,e codomain =range. But i don't know the other option whether it is correct or incorrect .

If anbody help me i would be very thankful to him?

Answer (score 3):

The assertions $a$ and $c$ are true.

a) $\dim\ker(T)+\dim \mathrm{Im}(T)=n$, $\lambda_i=0$ implies that $\dim\ker(T)>0$,, thus $\dim \mathrm{Im}(T)<n$ and $T$ is not surjective.

c) if a 3-dimensional vector space $U$ is stable by $T$, the degree of the characteristic polynomial of the restriction of $T$ to $U$ is a 3, so it has a real root which is an eigenvalue.

b) is not true since $2I_n$ is injective and it has one eigenvalue which is equal to $2$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Please do not remove material from answers given by other users (you removed the last sentence while editing this post just now, maybe accidentally).

Comment: @Shalop I did not mean to remove the last sentence---only to fix up the formatting---I can't imagine how that happened.  Sorry about that.